# Get line-number/tracebacks from Selenium/ChromeDriver execute_script() failures

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium

When the Javascript code executed with `driver.execute_script()` fails, you will get an error message but seemingly no context, such as a line-number or, perhaps, a stacktrace/traceback. It's not in the message nor is it stored in any of the attributes of the exception. It seems like this should be *somewhere*.

Example message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unexpected token ')'
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.47)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

I'm calling the webdriver from Python.

Comment: Please show us the code you're trying to execute.

Comment: I'm asking about how to get more information about the exception context. The code is not relevant.

Comment: The context helps.

Comment: @DMart the JS code the OP is trying to execute it doesn't really matter in the context of his question since the post is about the stacktrace of the JS executed from Selenium.

Answer (score 2):

The way how Selenium is executing the JavaScript is by running it in the body of an anonymous function.

The only workaround that I have found to be able to retrieve the stack trace is to place your JS code inside a `function` declaration and then use a `try..catch` statement that will retrieve the stacktrace in case something failed.

Let take the following simple `function` as an example:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log(testVar.a + testVar.b);
}
myFunction();
```

Running this in the browser console we will rightfully get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: testVar is not defined
    at myFunction (<anonymous>:2:21)
    at <anonymous>:4:5
```

However using it with `execute_script` from Selenium we will only get, as you already mentioned:

```
javascript error: testVar is not defined
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)
```

To get the error message and stack trace, call the `myFunction()` function inside a `try` statement and return the stacktrace in the `catch` clause like this:

```
    js_stack_trace = driver.execute_script('''
    function myFunction() {
        console.log(testVar.a + testVar.b);
    }
    try { 
        myFunction(); 
    } 
    catch (err) { 
        return err.stack;
    }
    ''')
```

The value of the `js_stack_trace` variable will be:

```
ReferenceError: testVar is not defined
    at myFunction (eval at executeScript (:480:16), <anonymous>:5:25)
    at eval (eval at executeScript (:480:16), <anonymous>:8:13)
    at executeScript (<anonymous>:482:30)
    at <anonymous>:487:24
    at callFunction (<anonymous>:450:22)
    at <anonymous>:464:23
    at <anonymous>:465:3
```

The downside with this approach is that the stacktrace is not quite exactly the correct one, because, as I said in the beginning, the JS will be executed inside an anonymous function, so the returned stacktrace will also take into account that.

However if the JS you're executing is pretty well formatted (for example the entire JS is not only on a single row) it will be easier to determine where the error is coming from.
Otherwise your best bet will be to play around a bit with it and see what the offset for column and row number is (taking into account the anonymous function).

Comment: I tried that too, but still couldn't seem to find the "lineNumber" member that i found suggested elsewhere. Not that this is also about JS in the context if Selenium. It'd be ideal if then the exception results in a line-number in the error seen from Selenium.

Comment: @DustinOprea are you getting the correct stacktrace if you're running the JS in Chrome devtools?

Comment: Sure, like you did above. I don't think there's going to be a resolution for this at this point in time. Thanks for giving it serious thought.

Comment: this solution is good enough to pinpoint the bug for me.

Answer (score -1):

[Unexpected Token](https://airbrake.io/blog/javascript-error-handling/unexpected-token#:%7E:text=Unexpected%20Token%20errors%20are%20a,different%20from%20what%20JavaScript%20expects.) errors are a subset of `SyntaxErrors` and hence will only appear when attempting to execute code that has an extra or a missing character in the syntax, which is different from what JavaScript expects.

In other words JavaScript exception [`unexpected token`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_token) occurs when a specific language construct was expected, but something else was provided which might be a simple typo.

Comment: The question is about how to extract a line-number or traceback from the exception. It has nothing to do with understanding the error.